# I can't change the image using label.configure

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

I am trying to create a GUI in which I can process images, so I have to change the default image to the one chosen by the browse button.
The default image disappears but the new image doesn't appear. Help Please! 
Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import cv2

class Browse_image :
    def __init__ (self,master) :

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.browse = Button(frame, text="Browse", command = lambda: self.browseim())
        self.browse.grid(row=13, columnspan=2)
        self.check = Checkbutton(frame, text="On/Off")
        self.check.grid(row=0)
        self.maxval = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.maxval.grid(row=1,columnspan=2)
        self.minval = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.minval.grid(row=2,columnspan=2)
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file="browse.png")
        self.label = Label(frame, image=self.photo)
        self.label.grid(row=3,rowspan=10)

    def browseim(self):
        path = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpeg")) )
        if path:
            self.photo = PhotoImage(path)                        
            self.label.configure(image = self.photo)
            #self.label.image = self.photo
            #self.label.grid(row=3,rowspan=10)


root= Tk()
b= Browse_image(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `self.photo = PhotoImage(path)` to `self.photo = PhotoImage(file=path)`. The `file` parameter is required to define an image path in [`PhotoImage` class](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm).

Comment: Thanks! But now it shows an other error:
"TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file"

Comment: This error message is usually raised when using an unsupported image type. Are you sure you are using a correct PNG file? Because `PhotoImage` does not support some image file types e.g. JPG, ICO. But it does support PNG.

Comment: thanks a lot! you're right: it only supports PNG files.

Comment: If I want to put an other image type I should use:
     from PIL import Image, ImageTk

     img = Image.open(path)
     self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)     
     self.label.configure(image = self.photo)

Comment: It supports GIF files too. And yes, as in the [source](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) I have mentioned above in my answer: "If you need to work with other file formats, the Python Imaging Library (PIL) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30 formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects".